# Problem creating a WebComponent from a SFC with Vue 3.2.9

Tags: web-component, vuejs3, vue-sfc

I am trying to create a web component in Vue3. For this I use the Vue cli with the target library. Everything works as expected.

The problem is that I can't get any values from the props parameter of the setup function.

If I use the component as a Vue component the props work. As a web component i cant get any value from the props parameter

Its seams that the property wc-Test is not forwarded properly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

The Component Code

```html
<template>
    <a class="btn">
        <slot></slot>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
import {version } from "vue";

export default {
    name: 'xn-button',
    props: {
        variant: {
            default: 'normal',
            type: String
        }

    },
    setup(props, context) {
        console.log(`Vue: ${version}`)
        console.log(props)
        console.log(props.variant)
    },
}

</script>

<style></style>
```

Usage as Part of Vue Library:

```
<xn-button variant="Vue-Test">Test1</xn-button>
```

Usage as WebComponent:

```
<xn-button variant="wc-Test">Test2</xn-button>
```

Console output:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30wJp.png)